# How to disable auto-login in WSL distros?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, auto-login, default-profile

I have an Ubuntu distribution running on WSL. Every load, it opens my user `lraj22` by default. Using an `/etc/wsl.conf` file, I set

```conf
[user]
default=
```

It still opens up my user profile. If I set it to `root`, it opens the root profile, and if I set it to some non-existent user `notarealuser`, it errors and goes back to mine.

If it's possible, how do I disable the auto-login feature on WSL distributions (specifically Ubuntu)?

Note: For reference, the question [How to set default user for manually installed WSL distro?](https://superuser.com/q/1566022/1460288) shows how to set the default user. I'm trying to *unset* the default user, so that it asks for a username/password in order to access the system.

Comment: There may be workarounds, but can you help me understand *why* you want to do this?  If you are thinking that it's a security issue, then see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1436089/1165986) for my explanation of why I don't believe it is (even in `root` form).  While I can probably give you a way to force a login, it wouldn't change the security aspects.  But if you have a different reason for wanting to change it, maybe there's a workaround.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I was testing out WSL/Ubuntu (pretty new to those topics), and I noticed that one difference between an Ubuntu VM and WSL Ubuntu is that WSL Ubuntu auto-logged in to my user. The `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` file from Google searches didn't apply to WSL. When I finally found out about `wsl.conf`, it didn't work either, so I asked here on SU. I didn't expect this to increase security, but rather free me from constant user switching (apparently `su` isn't the equivalent to sign out & sign in on Windows... you can `exit` to go back, and commands are logged as the invoking user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of such a method - it doesn't seem to exist.
You may use the Feedback Hub to signal the problem to Microsoft.

As a very weak workaround, you could set the default user to be an
extremely limited guest user account. This will force to do the real
login using the command `su - username`, which will require a password.

Comment: I had a similar idea with the limited guest user, but that won't be too helpful in my specific use case. Thanks for clarifying, though!

Answer (score 1):

There's always going to be one "default" user for a WSL distribution.  This is because [WSL distributions are "containers"](https://superuser.com/q/1736527/1210833).  A container doesn't have the concept of a "login", but rather is "entered" from the parent namespace.  Docker works the same way.

There are several possible workarounds.  From your comments, your issues with the current situation are:

> ... constant user switching
> ... `su` isn't the equivalent to sign out & sign in on Windows...
> ... [with `su`], you can exit to go back, and commands are logged as the invoking user

With that in mind, you can:

- Specify the username on the `wsl` commandline

  Launch WSL with:

  ```
  wsl ~ -u <username>
  ```

  This will enter the WSL distribution as another user.  You can even have multiple terminals open at the same time with different users.

  This is similar to the way the `docker exec --user <username>` form would work (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64461658/11810933)).

  After exiting the shell that was started this way, you'll actually exit the distribution itself (rather than being returned to a parent user).
- Not Recommended:  Use the `login` command directly when starting WSL

  ```
  wsl -u root -e login
  ```

  Advantage:  Runs all normal login activities, such as `/etc/profile.d` and PAM modules.

  Disadvantage:  Because a login goes through PAM, the environment variables that WSL itself sets are not available.  This includes:

  - The `PATH` that WSL provides with the Windows path appended.  So when running through `login`, you won't have access to `code`, `powershell.exe`, and other Windows commands without specifying their full path.
  - `DISPLAY` for running GUI applications in WSLg.
  - `WSL_xxx` variables
  - `WT_` information from Windows Terminal
  - And more.

  As a result, some WSL functionality will be degraded.